# i have to write query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT(project_id int not null primary key generated by default as identity,
project_template_id int ,p_name varchar(50) not null unique,
store_intv int not null , p_type int not null,
start_time timestamp ,stop_time timestamp, p_status int not null,
p_scheduled boolean not null, autorecovery_status boolean not null,
p_soource varchar(50)
);

Insert into Project(project_id,project_template_id,p_name,store_intv,p_type,start_time,
stop_time,p_status,p_scheduled,autorecovery_status,p_soource
)Values(1,1,'ABC',10,2,'2022-04-04 9:55:00','2022-04-04 10:55:00',
1,true,true,'this');

Insert into Project(project_id,project_template_id,p_name,store_intv,p_type,start_time,
stop_time,p_status,p_scheduled,autorecovery_status,p_soource
)Values(2,2,'BBB',16,23,'2022-04-05 9:55:00','2022-04-04 10:55:00',
1,true,true,'this');

Insert into Project(project_id,project_template_id,p_name,store_intv,p_type,start_time,
stop_time,p_status,p_scheduled,autorecovery_status,p_soource
)Values(3,3,'CCC',20,32,'2022-01-06 9:55:00','2022-04-04 10:55:00',
1,true,true,'this');
```

this is my structure of table i want to select tuples whose start_time is > todays date and also start_time >11 pm

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Does `start_time is > todays date` mean `2022-04-4` in which case you should specify it as absolute date or does it mean whatever the current date is when the query is run? Add answer as update to question.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres provides a extensive set of [date handling functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). In this case use `date_trunc` to get the current date to its midnight, then add the interval '11 hours' to produce the desired start time. So: (for server local timezone)

```
select * 
  from project
 where start_time > date_trunc('day', current_date) + interval '11 hours';
```